# Inserir Formula Matriz no Excel, via C#. ? (Se inserir direto pelo excel, tenho que dar Crtl - Shift - Enter) - Como fazer esse comando com C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, fórmula

O Código a seguir insere uma Fórmula em uma célula no Excel. Baseado na Planilha "DADOS", E De acordo com a coluna ao lado. 
Porém, essa Fórmula é uma Fórmula Matriz, que no Excel precisa ser inserida pelas teclas Ctrl + Shift + Enter. 
Diferente das Fórmulas Básicas, que só com o Enter já é inserida.

---

No Excel, essa Fórmula, inserida com as teclas Ctrl + Shift + Enter. Fica com {} entre elas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, no código se eu insiro essas {}, ele nem lê como Fórmula.

---

Segue o trecho do Código, que insere a Fórmula.

```
              if (!dado.Equals("Outros"))
                {
                    planilhaGrafico.Cells[i, j].Value = dado;

                    planilhaGrafico.Cells[i, j + 1].Formula
                        "=SUM(LEN(" + nomePlanilha + "!" + colunaGrafico
                        + ":" + colunaGrafico + ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" 
                        + nomePlanilha + "!" + colunaGrafico
                        + ":" + colunaGrafico + ",A" + i + ",\"\")))/LEN(A" + i 
                        + ")";
                }
```

---

Alguém sabe como Inserir uma Fórmula Matriz, pelo C#, no Excel.???

Pois, o comando `planilhaGrafico.Cells[i, j + 1].Formula`não insere corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer.

Resposta obtida no Link: [C# EPPLUS excel array formula workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665354/c-sharp-epplus-excel-array-formula-workarounds)

Ficou desta maneira:

```
planilhaGrafico.Cells[i, j + 1].CreateArrayFormula("=SUM(LEN(" + nomePlanilha + "!" + colunaGrafico
+ ":" + colunaGrafico + ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" + nomePlanilha + "!" + colunaGrafico
+ ":" + colunaGrafico + ",A" + i + ",\"\")))/LEN(A" + i + ")");
```